# TypeError: ... is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor, visual-studio-code

I am using protractor+typescript. Following is my code

Below is my eaApp_spec.ts

```
  import {browser, element, ElementFinder,by} from 'protractor';
     import { HomePage } from "./PageObjects/HomePage";

     describe("Going to write first test", () => {

     var homePage = new HomePage();

     it("should pass without any issue", () => {

        //Open browser
     homePage.openBrowser("http://localhost:8808/");

        //Get the headings
     homePage.getAllLinks();

        //Click the first heading
     homePage.clickFirstLink();
    });

    });
```

I am trying to implement POM and following is my HomePage.ts

```
import { browser, element, ElementFinder, by, $ } from 'protractor';

export class HomePage
{
  heading= element(by.xpath("//div[@class='well hoverwell 
  thumbnail']/h2[contains(text(),'Selenium Framework development')]"));

  headings= $(".well.hoverwell.thumbnail>h2");

  openBrowser(url:string)
  {
     browser.get(url);
  }

  getAllLinks()
  {
     this.headings.getText().then((text) =>{
         console.log("The links are" + text);

   });
  }

  clickFirstLink()
  {
     this.heading.click();
  }
}
```

this is my eaApp_spec.js file and is mentioned in specs in conf.js file and which will be run eventually

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var HomePage_1 = require("./PageObjects/HomePage");
describe("Going to write first test", function () {
    //Globally
    var homePage = new HomePage_1.HomePage();
    it("should pass without any issue", function () {
        //Open browser
        homePage.openBrowser("http://localhost:8808/");
        //Get the headings
        homePage.getAllLinks();
        //Click the first heading
        homePage.clickFirstLink();
    });
});
```

when i am running protractor conf.js , i am getting an error:

> TypeError: HomePage_1.HomePage is not a constructor

Comment: can you add `export default HomePage` at the end of the your HomePage.ts file and try.

Comment: Why do you have a eaApp_spec.js file? Try reference eaApp_spec.ts in your conf.js file.